# Spring boot Observablity for Event lifecycle

Tags: spring-boot, observability

I am creating a application with spring boot 3 and its observability feature using micrometer and actuators.
What my application does is, it receives a alert, generates event based on this alert, these events trigger some JS execution and the lifecycle of these JS executions and action which took place are saved in a database entity.
Now, I want to trace the lifecycle of a alert on prometheus and grafana. I am thinking to start a observation and put observation events to it for recieving alert, generation events and etc.But soon i realized that I have to use observation where I have declared it. I cannot get a already defined observation by its name. I want to create a observation based on alert Id and then close it in another class where this alert lifecycle ends.
Is it possible

I tried using observability. I cannot share much.